# Oracle XE 10g : Job Scheduling w/in a package or procedure : DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS

Tags: oracle, plsql, job-scheduling

I have a package that compiles fine in another 11g environment.
When I try to compile it in my XE 10g environment w/ a DBA User, I get the ORA-00942 error.

```
   FOR r IN (SELECT DISTINCT job_name jname
                        FROM dba_scheduler_jobs
                             ^
                       WHERE job_name LIKE p_job_prefix || '%')
   LOOP
      ...
```

When I execute a direct select on the table there is no issue.

```
   Select * from dba_scheduler_jobs;
```

Error Text:

```
   Line: 34 Column: 34  Error: PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to reference an object in a definer's rights stored procedure (the default), the owner of the procedure has to have direct access to the object.  The privilege cannot be granted through a role, even a very powerful role like `SYSDBA`.

You probably want to grant the owner of this procedure the `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY` privilege

```
GRANT select any dictionary
   TO <<owner of procedure>>
```

You could also grant the privileges on each object (i.e. `DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS`) individually but if you've already granted this user the `SYSDBA` privilege, you're probably not overly concerned with restricting grants.

Comment: Thanks, GRANT select any dictionary TO <user> worked perfectly for my local DEV.